# linux : accessing another machine

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access

I would like to know if it is possible to access another machine without setting remote control ON on the machine i wish to access.

for example, if i try to use the ssh command to access my windows machine from my linux laptop i get this error:

```
ssh -l existance (ip address of the machine)
ssh: connect to host (ip address of the machine) port 22: Connection refused
```

Is there anyway to bypass this? Do i need to do anything to access port 22? Or thats not the issue?

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: It would be good to actually copy and paste the errors you get, instead of typing them in with typos.

Comment: Im sorry for the typos, will correct them after this, but that was copy pasted directly from terminal, i only removed the IP itself.

Comment: and why did you remove the IP?

Comment: Because the windows machine belongs to a relative of mine ( my sibbling) who asked me not to share it, decision which i respected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access that machine it needs to run an `SSH daemon` (SSHD) on port 22 (the default SSH port). Is that the case currently?

Another thing to ensure is that a firewal isn't blocking the connection, but I'd set up `SSHD` first, and then investigate whether it's being blocked by a firewall.

Taking a guess `Remote control` most likely just runs a service opening up a specific port for incoming connections. I don't think it needs to be turned on to allow for SSH connections, once you have an SSHD set up to receive SSH connections on port 22.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm) a guide on installing `Cygwin`, and then inside Cygwin installing SSHD.

But perhaps another question is: For what purpose do you want to connect to the other computer remotely? Maybe there are better solutions than SSH?

If you update your question or comment here with more information about your situation, I can try to expand my answer.

Comment: i dont think i understand what you mean ( i am new to this sort of thing), what i did was simply opening the terminal on my dektop and running the ssh command. Do i need to go to a specific directory and run the ssh there?How do i run it at port 22?

Comment: Making an `SSH` connection really requires two different programs:
One of them runs on the computer that you're connecting *from*, and the other on the computer you're connecting *to*. You already have `SSH` installed in Ubuntu, but if you are to make an SSH connection to the Windows machine, then SSH (in it's *daemon* form, that *receives* the connection, which is called *SSHD*) also needs to be installed and running on that machine. If that seems overly complex to setup, maybe there's a different solution/tool that works better for you? For what purpose do you want to connect to it remotely?

Comment: Oh ok i understand that makes sense, i thought the the machine being accessed didnt need anything installed.
Is there any way to access without installing anything on the machine i wish to access?
Im going to leave my country for a couple of months and ill need to access my brother's desk computer in which i have some important documents and programs

Comment: If `SSH` is too much trouble to set up, and you prefer not to use `remote desktop`, what about using `Dropbox` or `Windows Onedrive` og something similar?: https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/ or maybe run an FTP server on the Windows machine, that you can log into? Fx. you could use `FileZilla` for running that server?: https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: That might solve the doc problem but i still would not be able to access certain programs.

Comment: Ah, right. They are programs that can run in a terminal, not requiring a graphical interface? If not you need something like remote desktop anyway (not just SSH alone), or VNC: https://www.realvnc.com/download/

Comment: None of them require graphical interface, all of them are suposed to run in the terminal itself.

Comment: Seems to be the only option i got.
I thought that there might be a way of doing this without installing anything.

Comment: Alright, in that case I do think setting up SSHD inside cygwin is the best option next to remote desktop. Still, then they need to be able to run inside cygwin, a linux environment. If they are binaries that could be a problem. Maybe then they could be run via `Wine`. If they are python scripts or something like that it would be easy though. If they're supposed to affect Windows on that machine that introduces even more complexity.

Comment: They are python and C scripts yeah.
Ill do the SSHD thing then.
I cant say how thankfull i am for the time you didicated to help me solv this issue, many many thanks.

Comment: **I** don't think it's possible without installing anything, at least. If remote desktop would be okay after all there are apparently linux programs that can connect to it:
http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu
In that case maybe you can avoid installing things on the Windows machine and only install things on your laptop.